# How to regenerate missing folders

Tags: craft3

TLDR:

**How do I re download / re generate the base Craft CMS folders / files if they are missing from a project?
*I know you can clone the base Craft CMS project from github (this might be the answer?)***

**Premis**

I have a project that was stored in GitLabs but only contains the basic folders for the Craft Projects (I.e. the custom or project specific folders/files):

[image]

As you can it is missing mostly all of the major folders / files for Craft CMS.

As I am wanting to do some local work using DDEV I was wondering if there is a **Best practice** approach to getting the base Craft cms folders / files into the local development area and then applying the project repo and importing the db?

I assume it would be to download a fresh Craft CMS install via git clone and then pull this repo over the top of it?

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are "missing" the `vendor/` directory and a `.env` file. I say "missing" in quote marks because typically you wouldn't include those things in a repository (check the .gitignore file to see all the things that are excluded from your repo).

To get up and running, you'll need to run `composer install` locally on the command line, which will create and populate a vendor directory based on your composer.lock file, and then create a file called `.env` and populate it with your preferred local environment settings and database connection credentials. It looks like you have a `.env.live` file in there which might give you a good starting point. (Usually that file would be called `.env.example` and would serve as a boilerplate for any new developers to create their own `.env` file.

Comment: Yeah great - so I had already done those steps, but was stupidly trying to import the DB via DDEV php craft db/restore instead of DDEV import-db --src=<Path to DB>
Thanks for your help!